# Problems in an imperative Apex call from a LWC function

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am using LWC in a Salesforce Community and I have an Apex imperative call which should query a record by the passed ID parameter and make an update to that record. For some reason it is returning a 'No results available System.QueryException'. I made sure that the parameter names are matching in the Apex method and in the passed Object.

Simplified version of the code below. Which is not working

**LWC JS function**
[image]

**Apex method (Simplified version, just trying to return the result of the query, all updates were removed)**

[image]

**Chrome Developer Console Network tab (Here you can see the correct values are being passed**

[image]

**Error**

[image]

I'm using the same query in Workbench and in the Salesforce Dev Console and it is returning records properly. Any help will be well received. Thanks.

Comment: Does the apex class have `with sharing`? Does the community user have relevant record access?

Comment: Yes sir, that was the issue. I did not grant access to the guest profile. Thank you, this solve the problem